# Div vs. iFrame - resizing issue

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jsfiddle

I am trying to create a resizable content pane, that will load from a local file<sup>1</sup> when different links are clicked on the main content side of the page.

I've tried two approaches. The first is to use a <div>, but I haven't found a good way to load from external sources<sup>2</sup> this way. So instead I am using an iFrame within a div.

However, I'm having some trouble resizing the main content properly using the iFrame. With similar code, the pure-div version resizes properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/jvnn6/4/

However, when I try using an iFrame, the content on the left half of the page aren't resizing correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/JX4yM/

Here, I added the following CSS:

```
  .ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 50px solid rgba(239, 239, 239, .9);
    margin: -75px;
}
```

and this to jQuery

```
helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
```

What's going on? (I had to add the .ui-resizable-helper because resizing works weird when the mouse moves over an iFrame. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/36S7p/1/)

====================================================================

<sup>1</sup>: I have no plans to host it online anytime soon

<sup>2</sup>: An alternative, of course, is to embed everything in my webpage itself, and just hide/reveal different parts in the right-hand pane as needed. There's some structural issues with that however, which I won't get into.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `<script>` tags from the Javascript pane and you're golden. Also you need to get body width not document width.

```
$('#resizable').on("resize", function (event, ui) {
     var setWidth = $("#resizable").width();
     $(".content").width($("body").width() - setWidth);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JX4yM/1/)**

Comment: A little better! But there seems to be a delay in terms of the content line-wrapping correctly. 

I'm also uncomfortable with the idea that document.width worked well enough in the first one, but not the second...